# Как найти радиус в процентах

Tags: html, jquery, css, математика

Есть `div` с заданным свойством `border-radius` в `px`. Как получить соответствующее значение `border-radius` в процентах? Что является базовым значением при расчете процентного `border-radius`?

Comment: А в процентах от чего вы хотите найти? Вот на это самое и делите.

Comment: % относительно чего?

Comment: @zkolya, не уверен что угадал с формулировкой.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/japfdL1t/1/ здесь добавляется новый див,нужно сделать щелчок по нему(сделать активным) и после менять бегунком радиус, при нажатии на radius он выводит его в px .Я и не понимаю относительно чего рассчитывать ширины или высоты,он у меня равномерно по ширине и по высоте.

Comment: @zkolya вы читали ответы?

Comment: Само собой разумеется

Answer (score 1):

Значение по высоте расчитывается относительно `height`, значение по ширине - относительно `width`:

```css
.rounded-percent
{
   background-color: red;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 25%;
}

.rounded-absolute
{
   background-color: green;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   margin-left: 120px;
}

.rounded-proportional
{
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 25%;
   margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-percent" />
<div class="rounded-absolute" />
<div class="rounded-proportional" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Что является базовым значением при расчете процентного border-radius?

Для горизонтального скругения ширина элемента, для вертикального - высота.
Поэтому 50% даст эллипс.

> Как получить соответствующее значение border-radius в процентах?

Считаешь долю относительно ширины и высоты элемента и записываешь в форме со `/`. Если у тебя уже различные вертикальные и горизонтальные значения разничны, то считаешь относительно соответствующей величины.